# To what extend I can use FTP?

Tags: internet, ftp, network-protocols

As far as I know that FTP is designed to help clients communicating with servers to download/upload files from/to the target server. If that server is secured then the client is required to key-in the credentials. However, if the server is public then the client should be able to download/upload from/to the server. My question is, Can we apply this concept for public servers such as Youtube, where we can just download any video without a need to thrid parties' software?

Please correct me if I have any misconception, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP (file transfer protocol) and its variants, such as sFTP, FTPS and SCP are all methods of exchanging files with a server.

This service is not inherently available on all servers. For example, an email server may or may not also host webpages. So, neither will a YouTube server also provide FTP services unless they specifically provide that service for you, which they do not.

Comment: So if a server provides a feature to use an FTP then I can, correct?


https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

This website provides a way to download PuTTy using FTP, but when I tried to do so, they asked for server credentials

Comment: @MuaathAlhaddad Yes. They need to provide the FTP service so that it can be accessed in the first place. Typically if you don't have explicit access and it is expected to be "open" access you can use `anonymous` as the username and your email as the password: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Anonymous_FTP

Comment: Web browsers usually try to log in as `anonymous` automatically. You only get the prompt when that doesn't work. In this case, it seems the server is temporarily rejecting anonymous access because "there are too many users using the system at this time" (according to the message it provides).